# Keeping same domain name, but changing web framework

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I have a website www.horschgallery.com that was built 10 years ago in asp.net by an outside consultant.  I am currently learning rails and will be developing and designing a new site.

How do I go about replacing the old framework with the new ruby on rails framework while still keeping the same domain and URL's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build your application in Ruby on Rails. deploy it on server (you can use heroku, amazon, rackspace etc). your server will have an IP address, just point that Domain url to new server IP.